# Is Cerberus capable of surviving phone flashing?

Tags: rom-flashing, anti-theft

If I install Cerberus on a rooted phone, will it survive flashing the phone?!!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you flash. Living on the `/system` partition, it will survive a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset). But flashing a new ROM would overwrite that partition and thus remove Cerberus.

If, on the other hand, you e.g. just flash GApps, Cerberus would survive – as that doesn't wipe/overwrite the `/system` partition.

Comment: and this applies to all other anti-theft apps, none of the existing ones survives wiping out the `/system` partition.

Comment: To my knowledge, that applies to all system apps – regardless of their purpose :)